# How can I change the style of an image to fit it to a reference image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, style

I try to Photoshop the head of a person I have taken into a generated poster image that has a more drawn stylistic style... and although I assume it is a pretty simple task, I have no idea how to really do this.

[image]

Comment: hi, i not yet have achieved what i tried to do, I only know rotoscoping from after effects and this is basically a moving mask ... i am able to do the masking in the image with photoshop... but I want to replace the face you currently see on the image with another one... problem is it would not have the same style of the image so I need to adapt the color etc... and I don't know what technique is required.... if I am wrong here , please point me to the right direction :) all suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: That's an illustration/painting. On would need to paint the new face in a similar fashion. It's not merely "photo editing". Photoshop filters such as "posterize" on a photo may help a little. However, ultimately it takes artistry. Kind of why artists still have jobs, at least until the artificial intelligent image generators have another year or so.

Comment: @Scott - actually I suspect that may in fact be AI art.  There are several odd things about it, look at it carefully.  Parts of the smoke with straight edges, weird text with no recognisable letters/characters, some kind of disjointed helicopter, a strange disjointed logo behind it, a weird swoosh behind the car which makes no real sense. Also, not a single match in google images reverse search.

Comment: For the OP, have a look at [this Photoshop tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHF8_OY6Mw4&t=5s). Should give you some ideas.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yeah I se all that, but the face certainly isn't AI "built"... it may be "AI Included" though.

Comment: @Scott yeah the face looks realistic enough, but the rest is a bit rubbish  ;)

Comment: It's possible each background part was AI generated and then the composite, with the face, was manual.

Comment: If you generated that image then why not edit in the new face and run the image through the AI with img2img to make the style more coherent?

Comment: Hi together, so the image is indeed a.I. generated . I used Midjourney for it and also the face is completely a.I.   image2image unfortunately does not provide the necessary recognizability I require from the a.I. as it unfortunately has its fair share of own interpretation.

Comment: I understand, but that's the deal with AI at the moment. It does incredible things but in a chaotic and uncontrollable way. Easier to just learn to like what you get than to get exactly what you want. I dabble a bit with Stable Diffusion. Have a look at [the Stable Diffusion subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StableDiffusion/). You might find some tricks that could help, but it will probably require some work. In Photoshop it's not a simple task either. Could require a mix of several techniques and the method would vary depending on the images and the wanted look.